# Ext.elCache[...].events' is null or not an object

Tags: extjs

Extjs 3, sometimes met this error when close a object or open a window/panel?
does any know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe this has something to do with an event handler closing (and destroying, including all event handlers) the object that defined it. I had some strange things that felt similar in the past. So the handler itself is destroyed while it's running...